# Heroku shows some images, not all

Tags: php, image, heroku

I've uploaded an old school yearbook project to Github. Locally the project is fine.

However, when deployed through Heroku, only two of the twenty images are shown - the others just show the alternative text. They function correctly (redirect to selected page) but are not visible.

What am I missing?

```
<li class="collection-item">
                    <div class="person">
                        <a href="Abdellatif El Mandili.html"><div id="photo1" class="photo"><img class="photo" 
                        src="Photos/Abde.PNG" alt="Photo d'Abdellatif El Mandili"/></div></a>
                        <p id="name1" class="name">Abdellatif El Mandili</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="collection-item">
                    <div id="person2" class="person">
                        <a href="Alexis-Mathieu Hubert.html"><div id="photo2" class="photo"><img class="photo"
                                src="Photos/Alexis.PNG" alt="Photo d'Alexis.PNG" /></div></a>
                        <p id="name2" class="name">Alexis-Mathieu Hubert</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

The code above shows code for would should appear as two photos and the person's name. Only 'Abdellatif' can be seen, and 'Alexis' photo is not loaded. There are 17 others like Alexi, and just one other like Abde. I'm sure all the code is the same for each list element, so what is the problem?

File is index.php

And ideas?

Comment: https://trombinoscope-group-project.herokuapp.com/ - problem page

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that uploading the images to a image-hosting site, then using the direct links works. I don't understand why the images were not showing before, but at least this solution might help others in the future.